# How to store char string in a string whole as unit in a string?

Tags: string

For example, I have

```
char name_1[] ="blabla";
char name_2[] ="walawala";
```

How do I put them in a string (names), so that I can call the letters in the char string when I use `names[n];`?

Comment: Hi 威豪曾, you should include more information to help people to give you an answer, like lanaguage you are using, version, or anything you think to be important.

Answer (score 0):

For cpp:

```
char name_1[] ="blabla";
char name_2[] ="walawala";
string str[] = {name_1, name_2};
cout<<str[0]<<" "<<str[1];
```

Edit:
For java :

```
 char[] name_1 ="blabla".toCharArray();
 char[] name_2 ="walawala".toCharArray();

  String []str = {String.valueOf(name_1), String.valueOf(name_2)};
  System.out.println(str[0] + " " + str[1]);
```